# Async await property access

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, async-await

I am writing a code similar to this one (I modified it here on stackoverflow, so probably it have typos) I have some doubts.

1. I know that sending a `PacketType.Rename` to this listener and a `PacketType.GetName`
   later, it could end, sending the `GetName()` result before I update the value on `Rename()`. Should I use a lock object on both methods before any
   logic to ensure "order"? Can I assume that the `BeginReceive()` task
   will not start reading next message until await `Rename()` is called
   and therefore, a lock on the first line inside `Rename()` should always
   be called before the code get the `PacketType.GetName` from the
   `NetworkStream`, call Execute and call await `GetName()`?
2. Same `PacketType.Rename` sent 10 times together, will get packets one
   by one on `BeginReceive()`, run `Execute()` and back to get the next one
   once the code reach await `Rename()`, so its possible `Rename()` method
   is running at the same time in multiple Tasks. If I don't care about
   which one is the latest one to update the value like this case (all
   renames are the same), or the updated value is not relevant like a
   Name, should I care?
3. If I want to use service/repository pattern on my async methods to
   run some CRUD against databases, while the service/repository only uses local variables and method parameters, should be fine to have a single instance of my service on `MockConnectionHandler` as a injected property? Each task should keep these independent from other tasks running the same service/repository?
4. Anything obvious I should avoid?

---

```csharp
public class Listener : IListener
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public int Connected {get;set;}

  ...
  private async Task Listen()
  {
    while (!_Token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
      tcpClient = await _Listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

      Connected++;
      IConnectionHandler connectionHandler = _ClientPool.Receive();
      connectionHandler.TcpClient = tcpClient;
      connectionHandler.Listener = this;  // really is done on the Listener init()
      connectionHandler.Init();
    }
  }
}
```

```csharp
public class MockConnectionHandler : IConnectionHandler 
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public int Messages {get;set;}
  public IListener Listener {get;set;}

  public void Init()
  {
     BeginReceive();
  }

  private void BeginReceive()
  {
    var receive = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
      while (true)
      {
        readedHeader = await _Stream.ReadAsync(dataHead, 0, headerLength, _DisconnectToken);
        // get body length from header.
        readedBody = await _Stream.ReadAsync(dataBody, 0, bodyLength, _DisconnectToken);

        Task run = Task.Run(() => Execute(headType, dataBody));
      }
    }, _DisconnectToken)
    .ContinueWith(previous =>
    {
      _EndReceiving = true;
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled);
  }

  private async Task Execute(PacketType type, byte[] data)
  {
    switch(packetType)
    {
      case PacketType.Echo:
         await SendAsync(new Bag(PacketType.Echo));
      case PacketType.Rename:
         await Rename(); 
      case PacketType.GetName:
         await GetName();
    }
  }

  private async Task Rename(byte[] data)
  {
    Name = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
    Listener.Name = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
  }

  private async Task GetName()
  {
    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Name);
    SendAsync(new Bag(PacketType.Echo, data));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you await on every async function like you are doing, the code will run "syncronously", but with potentionally reduced latency. If you can do stuff in parallel, then awaiting on every async method like that is bad, rather save the Task handle and await on an array of tasks later on when you need the result of all of them.

I.e. If you have asyncMeth1() and asyncMeth2() and they don't depend on each other / can run in parallel, you should not await on each one individually, but save the Task object and await on both later when you really need the result of both.

Comment: My bad, I didn't want to have await on the `Execute()` call, I updated the code so it have sense now with my previous questions :s Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you call await on a task the code returns to caller.  Once the task is complete it signals and the code then returns to that point in time.

This get's tricky only when you choose not to use await on every task.  If you run a task without await then that task is running parallel with your code as a separate thread would.  If you await that task you return to caller.

HOWEVER; to answer that I think you're asking... returning to caller doesn't return to the task prior that is awaiting.. it returns to the first call to await in the chain.  For example:  if you have a method that is awaiting a task, then the caller of that method is free to continue running... within that await if there is another inner await then no, your first await does not fire up and continue.  The tasks are chained together like a queue as when using await.

```
                → caller continues executing
caller → method → await task1 → await task2 → await task3 
                                                   ↓
                                             task3 complete
                                                   ↓
                                cont task2 ← -------
                                     ↓
                               task2 complete
                                     ↓
                   cont task1 ← ------
                        ↓
                 task1 complete
                        ↓
      cont method ← -----
           ↓
    method complete
           ↓
    (nothing to do)
```

It's worth mentioning that anywhere you skip the await keyword on a task it becomes a caller from that point in the chain.

Comment: My bad, I didn't want to have await on the `Execute()` call, I updated the code so it have sense now with my previous questions :s Sorry!